# Why is ICONV command hanging in Windows 10 when it's not supposed to?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, git-bash, iconv

As mentioned in the Question title, when Windows 10 is running normally with no process hanging, then why when I run this command in GitBash (even if I run GitBash as Adminiatrator) it just hangs and never finishes the command execution:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le | clip.exe
```

It mustn't unexpectedly hang like that.

Any ideas how to force it to completion and how to debug and resolve this ??

Comment: It's blocking waiting for input.

Comment: How to provide default blank input in such cases so it doesn't wait at all ?

Comment: Why are you running it if you don't have input to convert (a file, output of another program, something you're typing manually, etc.)? What are you expecting?

Comment: @Shawn The clip.exe must conform to the UTF-16LE encoding before I store password, i.e. copy password to clipboard... Next command if you use imagination would be `echo $GITPSWD | clip`... Password must not have any limitations on what characters it can contain... Best way I know is this way, any ideas on resolving the issue?